# External database connection passing authentication errors on Heroku app

Tags: javascript, heroku

I've been having a strange issue where I've created a basic Nodejs API that I'm trying to host on Heroku which works perfectly from a local standpoint but as soon as I try to test through Heroku I get an authentication error when a MySQL connection is attempted.

From what I can see, when doing Postman tests, Heroku is adding information to my connection information which then causes authentication failure. Authentication to the API itself works but fails the MySQL connection.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const utils = require('./utils');
 
const app = express();

const leadsdb = mysql.createPool({
  host: "hostIP",
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: "database",
}); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
 
// enable CORS
app.use(cors());
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/api/register", (req, res) => {
  
  const firstName = req.body.firstName
  const lastName = req.body.lastName
  const email = req.body.email
  const number = req.body.number
  const country = req.body.country
  const age = req.body.age
  const occupation = req.body.occupation

  const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Leads (FirstName, LastName, Email, Country, Phone, Age, Occupation) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
  leadsdb.query(sqlInsert, [firstName, lastName, email, country, number, age, occupation], (err, result) => {
    if(!result) {
      res.send(err)
    }
    else {
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
```

```
{
"code": "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR",
"errno": 1045,
"sqlMessage": "Access denied for user 'username'@'ec2-54-170-17-28.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)",
"sqlState": "28000",
"fatal": true}
```

If I'm not mistaken, the '@'ec2-54-170-17-28.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is not supposed to be included in the login information and it was not passed in where the DB connection is referenced.

I don't know if this is enough information so please ask for anything that may be needed. Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: you need to GRANT that user access to your database.  Or you need to fully qualify your login user using the  'user@hostname'    format. You were probably developing locally on your own computer so it was automatically using 'username@localhost'  for you.   But now you have the database up in the cloud so you need to modify your login appropriately.

Comment: The database I'm connecting to is hosted on a hostgator CPanel for a website that I'm hosting for a friend. With that subscription, I can have many SQL servers so I've used that for testing purposes. So when I connect to the database from the local setup, it's calling the database on the hostgator server, which works, but won't work when pushing the same information through Heroku.

Comment: How did you migrate the db from development to Heroku?  Can we assume that you migrated over the same Users table and it has the same login accounts?

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to use a database from within Heroku, I'm trying to get the external database as it stands. So the database connection hasn't changed at all

Comment: You just need to fully qualify your db login so that the hostname is not automatically appended for you.  You need to look at the User table of your database and look at the Host field for your user record. Whatever hostname is in that field is what you should tack onto your user login.

Comment: Thanks, Rex, but still a no-go. I appended the hostname as follows: user@hostname. If that is what you meant then I can confirm it wasn't the winner in this case. I did the same with the IP as well just for testing sake but also nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you haven't specify the `port`. While connecting to a remote database from Heroku you should use these fields:

```js
host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'db_name',
        insecureAuth: true
```

there is a one option also that you created a connection string like

```sh
DATABASE_URL=mysql2://username:password@ip.goes.here/data_base_name --app heroku-app-name
```

and specify it in your .env fil.
This makes the process lot more easier.

Comment: Thank you for this but still nothing I'm affraid. I had the port specified before but it also wasn't working at the time, I took it out for testing.

I tried using the database URL approach but it still seems to override the IP with the amazon connection info. I tried using the domain info too but still nothing.

Comment: Read more here about NodeJs api for MySQL http://stayregular.net/blog/quick-tips-using-remote-mysql-for-heroku-nodejs-api

Answer (score 0):

I realised that Hostgator has IP whitelisting rules for remote access to the hosted SQL servers. So Heroku wasn't appending anything to the connection, the server was actually responding saying the connection isn't allowed from the requesting hostname.

I appreciate all the help and I'm sorry for wasting the time of those who helped out.